# GoogleDrive API - generateIds

Tags: api, google-drive-api, upload

Does anyone know if generated ids has lifetime? Do they expire?

I did not find any information in the docs

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/generateIds

Thanks in advance

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/generateIds